# Is it possible to trigger "Set my default styles" with the Google Docs API?

Tags: google-docs-api

I'm trying to trigger this action with the API: Format > Paragraph styles > Options > Use my default styles.

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to use these default styles on the creation of a document or when you run your Google Docs API function?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Let's say I have an existing document and I update my default styles somewhere else.  I'd like to be able to send an API call to update the existing document to use the new default styles.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, at the moment of this answer it is not possible on the [Google Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api) to set the document styles to your saved `default styles`.

#### Workaround

However, as a possible workaround to this, you could use a [batch request](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate) to update your [document style](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updatedocumentstylerequest) with a default saved style on your script (or update the [paragraph style](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updateparagraphstylerequest), [table style](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updatetablecellstylerequest), etc).

If you want to ask for this functionality you can create a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=555502&template=1211190).